# Gson to convert JSON to Object that contain HastMap of Objects?

Tags: android, json, gson

I have a problem that I have no idea about this, can anyone help me:
Ex we have a json:

```
    {
      "status":"0",
      "result": {
        "object1": {
          "name":"name1",
          "age":"21"
        },
        "object2": {
          "event":"new year",
          "date":"date"
        },
        "object1_1": {
          "name":"name2",
          "age":"22"
        },
        "object2_1": {
          "event":"birthday",
          "date":"date"
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: what you want to do? you have this in HashMap?

Comment: no,I don have hastmap. I just get an api that give this json, so how can I create java object to map with this json. In the "result" there are many items "object1" and "object2" that look like a hastmap. bcoz I think I cannot put it all in a list of object, right ??

Answer (score 1):

you can try convert to object by using jackson json.
http://jackson.codehaus.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deserialize this json to an object that contains a Map (and the map contains litteral values and other maps). Assuming you have a bean similar to :

```
class MyBean {
    int status;
    Map<String, Object> result;
}

MyBean myBean = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, MyBean.class);
```

It should work with no modification. Note that if the type of status is not a number I'm not sure Gson does the conversion as in the json string the value is quoted, same thing applies to your "age" property.

You can also have a look at Genson library http://code.google.com/p/genson/ it has most Gson features, other ones that no other library provide and has better performances. Have a look at the wiki http://code.google.com/p/genson/wiki/GettingStarted.

**EDIT**

Are the names really things like object1_1, object2_1 etc? When looking at the structure I imagine that object1 goes with object2 and so long. If you use gson you can write a custom TypeAdapter http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html.

So you can create a root object similar to

```
 class Response {
     int status;
     List<MyObject> result;
 }

 class MyObject {
     String name;
     int age;
     String event;
     String date;
 }
```

In the read method of your TypeAdapter you should compose instances of MyObject based on the keys (object1 with object2, object1_1 with object2_1...) or take a similar approach.
If you want more details on how to do that you can also ask on Gson google group.

Comment: I cannot find the new Gson().fromJson("");

Comment: Missed the second argument, the type. Edited that

Comment: Hmmm but there many item in it, should we can use Map? normally it is given in for list of Object, But this time the Object in the list is all difference so how can I do ? Can u help ? Thank